# Removing numbers from dataframe that lie within range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a pandas dataframe that contains values between -1000 to 1000. I want to eliminate all the numbers between the range of -0.00001 to 0.00001 i.e replace them with NaN. It is worth mentioning that my df contains numerous instances of very small positive and negative numbers that I want to include within this range as well e.g. 6.26478E-52.

How do I go about doing this?

**P.S.** I am attaching an image of the first few rows of my df for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use if need less like `-0.00001` and `0.00001`:

```
df = df.mask(df.lt(-0.00001) | df.lt(0.00001))
```

is same like below `0.00001`:

```
df = df.mask(df.lt(0.00001))
```

Or if need values between:

```
df = df.mask(df.gt(-0.00001) & df.lt(0.00001))
```

Comment: ```df = df.mask(~(df.lt(-0.00001) | df.gt(0.00001)))``` gave me the desired output. Thank you! :)